# How to change height of text field?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way to change the height of a text field in IB?

If not, what is the proper way to do it in code?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Click the **attribute inspector** for the **textField** and then change the Border style to second one and you will be able to change the height.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

**Step 1 :** Click the **Attribute Inspector**, Select the `Border Styles` which is not the rounded one.

[image: borderstyle]

**Step 2 :** Now go to **Size Inspector** and change the size of the **TextField**.

[image: change the height of the textfield]

**Step 3 :** Create an `@IBOutlet` for TextField and then add below code inside the `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()`.

```
userTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
```

**Swift 5.7**

```
userTextField.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
```

Now you'll get the cool rounded textfield.

Comment: doesn't work with me in xcode 10.2.1. the width and height are disabled

Comment: Which border style you are using ?

Comment: It's showing in Xcode 11 beta 4 with None, Line and Bezel border style.

Comment: For XCode 12.4 the height and width in Size Inspector is disabled. I picked up the border style you mentioned. Could it be because of I put the TextField inside a Vertical StackView? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Change to square border style and then go back to rounded border and it will stay the same. This works for xCode 11.0

Answer (score 1):

In the **attribute inspector** of your textField you can select the first, second and third **Border Styles** to increase the height.