# Text is not centered when increasing the height of Textfield?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I was looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096586/how-to-change-height-of-text-field) on increasing the height size of textfield. However, I have an issue when I have the height of 40, I get this [image][image]

This can be solved by increasing the **font size**, but how do I keep the font size the same?

Comment: Can you see what happens when you run the app? This might be some problem with xcode

Comment: Its a bug in xcode9, when you run it , it gives you the expected result but in preview and storyboard this bug remains.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore  Yes it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Inder Kumar Rathore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468724/inder-kumar-rathore), and [@Saheb Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3755838/saheb-roy) pointed out that it's a bug in xcode. When you run it, it is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Show this screenshot and try it
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just  need to clear your text property and only need to give placeholder text.

[image: Text Field height is 40]

You don't need to worry just run your code and check on device or simulator your input text will be looking fine.

Hope it helps you.